# What is a good django admin-like tool for postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am looking for a tool that will give a few people the ability to muck around in our database.  Currently I write custom SQL queries every time we need to do something we don't have tools for.  I don't want to write more tools because more often than not I only need to do a particular operation once or twice.

I need to something so that other people can make changes in the database as well.  phppgadmin is going to be too complicated of an interface into the database for the people who will be using it (bitfeilds).

I have used the django admin in the past and really liked it, but it won't work well with our existing database.  I don't want django adding tables into there, and I REALLY don't want to modify our existing tables (django's ORM wants there to be exactly one primary key).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a desktop application, I'd highly recommen [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/). Much better than phpPgAdmin, in my opinion.

Disclaimer: I've never used the Django admin interface, so I have no idea if pgAdmin is anything like it. I just recommended it because that's my tool of choice.

Comment: pgAdmin looks like a good tool, it is a bit more 'know what you're doing'-oriented than I'd like but I'll use it if nothing better turns up.

Django's admin interface is quite nifty.  When you are writing the code that defines your database its just a couple extra lines to make it editable in the admin.  After that you can easily make changes to how the UI interface appears.

This is what it looks like: http://devpicayune.com/pycon2008/django_admin.html#enabling-admin

Comment: Yeah I've definitely seen the Django admin interface in screenshots and such, but I've never used it myself. But yes, pgAdmin does take some getting used to, especially if (like me) you're coming from a different database that does things differently. I just don't know of anything that's more like the Django interface.

Answer (score 0):

You want phpPgAdmin: [phpPgAdmin is a web-based administration tool for PostgreSQL. It is perfect for PostgreSQL DBAs, newbies and hosting services.](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: phppgadmin would be nice, but the database is too complicated for the people who would be using it.  There are bitfeilds that I have to count on my fingers to set correctly.  Thats what I liked about django's admin, that I could define the interface presented to a user for a given field.  Is there something like that in phppgadmin?